# I get broken file url from the parse server

Tags: java, android, android-studio, parse-platform, parse-server

I recently created an EC2 instance on AWS,and I uploaded a pdf file to the parse dashboard, but when I try to get the file URL, it returns a broken url, even if I try to download it directly through the dashboard, same url opens,
Here is the code I used to retrieve the file url from the parse server:

```
object.getParseFile("pdf").getUrl()
```

and this is the url returned:

> http://{server}/undefined/files/209757194dab964e98a7ba0191128d826c8aea5d/05143d2aa9af7c13669a0a7e19377a9d_a.pdf

I have uploaded Files before but they were all in the different instance, is there a need to configure parse server or the EC2 instance to upload a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this problem was solved once i used the older version of parse, i don't know if the new versions require special configurations to perform file handling, but the one launched on 8th August works fine.